# Timezone independent datetime lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, timezone

As of Sunday we've been running into a problem with our query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / 5 AS count 
FROM [dbo].[LogisticalOrderLines_shadow] 
WHERE SentToBI >= DATEADD(MINUTE, 55, GETDATE())
```

This should return the average messages sent per minute (based on the last 5 minutes) However since Monday this query has not been returning the expected results.

We are using our local time zone (was utc+1, now is utc+2) to store the time in our database. In order to prevent having to change this every half year i would like to turn this into a query which always functions no matter the timezone the server is in. but this seems to be quite an issue since we don't store utc times...

How would I go about this if it is even possible.

PS: a very strange thing happened where just for a few hours this morning I had changed the query to use -5 instead of +55 and it actually worked, that was the only way to get the correct amounts. Now however I had to change it again to 115 (which is actually what I would expect, it being UTC +2 and such). So this was quite strange and I do not have an explanation for it.

Comment: Seems like you should be storing the UTC times, not your local times.

Comment: Even without DST changes, your query doesn't check anything for the prior 5 minutes. It checks where the data in `SentToBI` is 55 minutes or more into the future.  That seems odd, as *sent* would seem past-tense, so how would it ever be in the future?  Also, counting rows and dividing by 5 will not give you average rows per minute for last 5 minutes, unless you are relying on some other characteristic of your data you didn't explain here.

Comment: As to the DST part, you could use `AT TIME ZONE` to convert the left side to `datetimeoffset` type and use `sysdatetimeoffset()`  instead of `getdate()` on the right.  But you'd have performance issues on large data sets, and it wouldn't help you in the fall DST when an hour is duplicated.  You're much better off using a `datetimeoffset` column for this to begin with.  (You could put either UTC or local time into that column.)  Also I'm assuming it is of type `datetime` or `datetime2` presently?